# How can I use VBA in Excel to find a free slot in the other persons calendar and pull back in to my sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel spreadsheet with names, emails, Meeting date and meeting times, How can i get ans import a time slot from a recipients calendar to make/suggest an appointment time and get that info back in to the excel spreadsheet while making sure the dates and times fall within 9-5 Mon-Fri

Please bare in mind Im still quite new to VBA so code would be fantastic and instructions would be even better :)

Thanks

(Thanks for the "-1" on my question too :D )

---

So far i have managed to get excel -> outlook to get the information only when i specify a set date and a set user eg;

```
Public Sub GetFreeBusyInfo()

    'launch Outlook
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Set myNameSpace = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    ' who's calendar
    Set myRecipient = myNameSpace.CreateRecipient("person@email.com")
    Dim myFBInfo As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    'when and how long to look for
    myFBInfo = myRecipient.FreeBusy(#1/30/2014#, 60 * 24, True)
    MsgBox myFBInfo
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Cannot access the information. "
End Sub
```

, but it is reporting back im the message box something like "001010101101101011100100" I understand that in my case its saying 0= free and 1= busy but how can i change that back to a manageable date and time that i can then drop the msgbox and insert it to a cell?

Also would it be best to screen the out of hours times before or after pulling the info back to excel as im only looking for one date and time?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of what you are asking, it seems that you are wanting to get information from Outlook into Excel and manipulate it.

I would advise trying it yourself, with being new to VBA it's often best to try it first as at least then you get an understanding of where the code is coming from and how it works. I have not long learned Outlook automation in Excel VBA and glad I did it mostly off my own back as it helps you more in the long run.

I will help point you in the right direction though...

What you need to do is generate an Outlook "Object" and run your VBA from there. A link explaining the basics of what can be done can be found on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb206737(v=office.12).aspx

As you will be working with Calendars, you will be using the `AppointmentItem` code. More on that can be found on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem.aspx

Hopefully this will at least point you in the right direction as to how to go about it.

Comment: Thanks, its taken me a lot more goggling to get this far. ive updated my workings so far above.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a rather old question but I'll try to answer it ...

The [FreeBusy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220097(v=office.11).aspx) method you are using returns a String of time slot information. If the 3rd parameter of the method (called "CompleteFormat") is true, then each character contains the value of a Outlook.OlBusyStatus member (which is olBusy=2, olFree=0, olOutOfOffice=3, olTentative=1, olWorkingElsewhere=4). If the CompleteFormat parameter is false, then "1" means busy and "0" indicates a free time slot.

The method always returns the free/busy information of one month starting with the given date (1st parameter). The length of the time slot is determined by the 2nd parameter of the method call. This parameter specifies the length of one time slot in minutes - you specified 24 * 60 which means that each character represents a full day. So in your example the first character shows the free/busy information for the entire day #1/30/2014#, the 2nd character is for #1/31/2014# and so on. I have no information how the status is calculated from a time span that has different states but I assume that the "worst" state is taken.

Please note that the method starts the time slots with the time 00:00:00  of the day you specified. So if you specify a start-date including time information as the 1st parameter, then the time information is ignored.

That being said, you might be looking for something like the following:

```
    resolution = 60 * 24
    startDate = #1/30/2014#
    myFBInfo = myRecipient.FreeBusy(startDate, resolution, True)
    For i = Len(slots) To 1 Step -1
        s = CInt(Mid(slots, i, 1))
        If s = olFree Or s = olTentative Then
           slotDate = DateAdd("n", (i - 1) * resolution, startDate)
           Debug.Print Format(slotDate, "dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM")
        End If
    Next
```

If you want to get more "sofisticated" results, then it is a good idea to fetch the free/busy information in smaller time slots (i.e. 15 minutes) than the overall time slot you are searching (i.e. 60 minutes) and then calculate all possible slots on your own.

This is how I implemented a search for a common free time slot for multiple recipients:

- For each recipient:

  - Fetch free/busy information in 15 minute time slots
  - Generate an array of all possible 1 hour slots (= 4 time slots in a row must be free) that are also part of the previous recipient's free 1 hour slots
- Return first element of resulting array

Comment: It's been along time since I was looking in to this but I'm thinking of digging it back out for future use.  I'm hoping that with your info I could actually get this abut further from where I left off.  Now.... Where did I save it...